# MongoDB + Mongoose Aggregate w/ Asnyc

Tags: mongodb, express, asynchronous, promise, mern

I've got the following route in my express file, which takes parameters passed in from a middleware function and queries my backend MongoDB database. But for some reason, it only ever returns an empty array.

I'd like to convert the Mongoose model that allows me to use aggregate functions into async/await to conform with the rest of my code. It's online `here`.

```
module.exports = {
    search: asyncWrapper(async(req, res, next) => { // Retrieve and return documents from the database.
        const { 
            filterTarget, 
            filter, 
            source, 
            minDate,
            maxDate, 
            skip, 
            limit,
            sortBy,
            sortOrder
        } = req.search;

        try {
            const mongoData = await Model.aggregate([
                {
                    $match: { 
                        date: {
                            $gt: minDate, // Filter out by time frame...
                            $lt: maxDate
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $match: { 
                        [filterTarget]: filter // Match search query....
                    }
                },
                {
                    $set: {
                        [filterTarget]: { $toLower: `$${filterTarget}` } // Necessary to ensure that sort works properly...
                    }
                },
                {
                    $sort: {
                        [sortBy]: sortOrder // Sort by date...
                    }
                },
                {
                    $group: { 
                        _id: null,
                        data: { $push: "$$ROOT" }, // Push each document into the data array.
                        count: { $sum: 1 }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        _id: 0,
                        count: 1,
                        data: { 
                            $slice: ["$data", skip, limit]
                        },

                    }
                }
            ])

            return res.status(200).json({ data: mongoData.data || [], count: mongoData.count || 0 });

        } catch (err) {
            next(err);
        }
    })
};
```

For some reason, the route is only returning an empty array every time. I've double and triple checked my variables, they are not the problem.

How can I use the Mongoose.aggregate() function in an async await route?

Comment: can you list the sample data, on top of which you are doing the query? and the inputs ?

Comment: `// Filter out by time frame...` - So your input here would appear to be "strings" and **not** `Date` objects. `aggregate()` does not do *autocasting* of types based on the model like `find()` or other methods does using mongoose. [This is by design](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1599#issuecomment-21948164) since aggregate is *meant* to alter the shape of the document from what the model has. Hence you cannot use the model for type casting. Use `new Date()` wrapping your string arguments in order to convert the types manually instead

Comment: Also, You loose a lot of efficiency by not including ALL criteria in the initial `$match` stage. That is in fact the **only** place where the database can correctly select an index to use and perform the most efficient query. Also note `$set` is **not valid** for an aggregation pipeline stage name. You actually appear to want `$addFields` here instead.

Comment: Hey Neil, thanks for the pointer on $match, will make the change. My “dates” are actually being stored as numbers, so that’s not the problem. PS — There is actually a $set operator in 4.2, which is what I’m using: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/.

Comment: I think the problem has to do with my route not waiting for the Mongoose function...it’s an asynchronicity problem, not a problem with the search itself...

Comment: `req.search` - This is **always** "string" input. You still need to cast here. `parseInt` or similar would be appropriate for numbers. Also FYI `mongoData` is an **array**. So `mongoData.data` and the `||` is not valid. Aggregate **always** returns just an empty array or the actual results *as an array* anyway. Not an async problem. But a problem with your inputs and the end logic. And yes `$set` and `$addFields` are just aliased to the same thing. I personally don't like it since people might assume this means *updating*. And that is not true. And the former does not break in earlier versions

Comment: Ah, amazing! So close––now, the last problem that I'm having (and it's a weird one) is that the variable won't take in my regex search. Like when I'm including the text itself, the thing works fine. But when I try to swap that out with a variable it's not working. Any idea why that might be?